# Method returning null Class

Tags: java, class, null

I think maybe this could be a design problem but I have a problem with a method that should return a specific class that is passed in the method. However, the method should return the modified class but it returns null.

```
AnimalSummary animalSummary = new AnimalSummary()
for (animal : animals){
    animalSummary = new Zoo().calculateAnimalTypeLegs(animal, animalSummary)
}
```

This is the method

```
AnimalSummary calculateAnimalTypeLegs(Animal animal, AnimalSummary animalSummary){

    if (animal.type.equals("Bear")
        animalSummary.setTotalLegs(animalSummary.getTotalLegs()+4)
    if (animal.type.equals("Human")
        animalSummary.setTotalLegs(animalSummary.getTotalLegs()+2)

    return animalSummary
}
```

While iterating through all the elements the first class is initialized correctly, but after the first return of the method and the second element the class animalSummary is null.

While debugging the first time the method gets the animalSummary class is correctly initialized. However it is after returning the value and entering in the second iteration that the animalSummary class is null

Comment: where you create animalSummary. give more code

Comment: Our God of Programming Debuger what say?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get

Comment: Why don't make `calculateAnimalTypeLegs` as `public static` and call it like this `animalSummary = calculateAnimalTypeLegs(animal, animalSummary)` . You no longer need an instance call it.

Comment: give us a complete snippet you are running, this one doesn't even compile

Comment: I copied your code and everything is working...either you missed some crucial part of the code or you are mistaking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried recreating your problem from what little code you provided:

```
public class Animal {

    public String type;
}

public class Zoo {

    public AnimalSummary calculateAnimalTypeLegs(Animal animal, AnimalSummary animalSummary){

        if (animal.type.equals("Bear"))
            animalSummary.setTotalLegs(animalSummary.getTotalLegs()+4);
        if (animal.type.equals("Human"))
            animalSummary.setTotalLegs(animalSummary.getTotalLegs()+2);

        return animalSummary;
    }
}

public class AnimalSummary {

    public int getTotalLegs() {
        return totalLegs;
    }

    public void setTotalLegs(int totalLegs) {
        this.totalLegs = totalLegs;
    }

    private int totalLegs;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Animal bear = new Animal();
        bear.type = "Bear";

        Animal human = new Animal();
        human.type = "Human";
        List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(bear, human);

        AnimalSummary animalSummary = new AnimalSummary();
        for (Animal animal : animals){
            animalSummary = new Zoo().calculateAnimalTypeLegs(animal, animalSummary);
        }

        System.out.println(animalSummary.getTotalLegs()); 
    }
}
```

**Input:** Bear; Human

**Result:** 6

As you can see, everything is working and animalSummary is not null at any point. Can you point out what's the difference between this and your code?

Comment: Since you accepted it is an answer, note that this can and should be improved. (I just wanted the code to be like yours). For example use setters/constructors to set data for Animal class, don't create Zoo class for each iteration, you don't have to assign animalSummary every iteration either. There are more, but these are basics

Answer (score 0):

try using this code :

```
List<AnimalSummary> animalSummaryList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (animal : animals){
        AnimalSummary animalSummary = new AnimalSummary();
        animalSummaryList.add(new Zoo().calculateAnimalTypeLegs(animal, animalSummary));
}
```

and after all iterations get the resulted animalSummaryList and iterate it for your results.

Comment: that's rather a guess than an answer, we don't know how OP wants to fill `AnimalSummary`

Comment: you don't want to create a new `Zoo` at each iteration